# Date values are not pushed into the database in the right way

Tags: mysql, r

I have a database on phpmyadmin and have a column called "Date" that has date as type.

Now I would like to push a value into this column but I do not seem to get it into the database into the right way.

I have the value var1 that is of date class.

```
class(var1)
[1] "Date"
```

And is structured in the right way:

```
> var1
[1] "2016-02-22"
```

But still  when I do:

```
 fn$dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(Date) VALUES('$var1')")
```

The following values are pushed into the database:
    0000-00-00

That's strange cause when I enter:

```
fn$dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(Date) VALUES('2012-02-02')")
```

It does work. But either of this:

```
var1
[1] "2016-02-22"
fn$dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(Date) VALUES('var1')")
fn$dbGetQuery(con, "INSERT INTO weather(Date) VALUES('$var1')"
```

Does not seem to work. Any thoughts on what goes wrong here?

Comment: Check by removing  '' (single quotes) arround $var1

Comment: No, that does not work

Comment: please re-check the $var1 . it should return a date format